# Using \sim with \overset with elegant vertical and horizontal spacing

Tags: math-mode

I would like to have have an equation like `a \in \overset{\sim}{\mathcal{G}}`, where the vertical spacing between `G` and `\sim` is lessened but where horizontal spacing between `G` and other elements in the equation is maintained.

I've tried using combinations of `\stackrel` and `\smash`, which work fine for vertical spacing but not the horizontal spacing.

Comment: Why not just `\widetilde`, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a \in \widetilde{\mathcal{G}}\]
\end{document}`?

Comment: This is a good alternative! Though it's not the optimal aesthetic I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a sketch that explains how that should look like in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}


\[ a \in \accentset{{\sim}}{\mathcal{G}} \]

\[ a \in \accentset{{\scriptstyle\sim}}{\mathcal{G}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it - thank you!